# Facebook-ios-sdk API Error Code: 11

Tags: ios, facebook-like

I use Facebook-ios-sdk in Cocos2d and I got an error on simulator screen
" API Error Code:11
API Error Description: This method is deprecated
Error Message: Display=wap dialogs have been deprecated. You can temporarily enable them by
disable the "july_2012" migration. They will Stop working permanently on July 1, 2012."

Anyone know how to solve this error ?

Thank you.

Comment: what about not using a deprecated method ? it will only cause you troubles in the future...

Comment: How about, if you could post some of your facebook Integration code???

Answer (score 0):

I followed exactly in the officer web https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/ios/build/

```
    - (void) applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication*)application
{
    facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:@"My ID" andDelegate:self];

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    if ([defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"] 
        && [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"]) {
        facebook.accessToken = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
        facebook.expirationDate = [defaults objectForKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
    }   

if (![facebook isSessionValid]) {
    [facebook authorize:nil];
}
```

}

```
- (void)fbDidLogin {
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:[facebook accessToken] forKey:@"FBAccessTokenKey"];
[defaults setObject:[facebook expirationDate] forKey:@"FBExpirationDateKey"];
[defaults synchronize];
```

}

```
    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {
    return [facebook handleOpenURL:url]; 
}
```